# Pex report PexAssumeFailedException in factory method

Tags: pex

everyone! I am a beginner in unit testing. I'm now testing a project with visual studio 2010 and Pex, and I encountered the following problem.

**When I run the Pex Exploration, and Pex tell me "could not create an instance of Root.Reports.Type1FontData", and the details message Pex reported is:**

---

```cs
[TestMethod]
[PexGeneratedBy(typeof(FontDataTest))]
[Ignore]
[PexDescription("the test state was: assumption violation")]
public void sGetTextLineThrowsPexAssumeFailedException500()
{
    string s;
    int i = 0;
    s =
    this.sGetTextLine((FontData)null, (string)null, 0, ref i, TextSplitMode.Line);
}
```

--- Exception details

Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Exceptions.PexAssumeFailedException: FontDataTest.sGetTextLine(FontData, String, Double, Int32&, TextSplitMode) at segment index 0 needs object of type Type1FontData (some object#0); extended sequence by ExSig#1

---

---

**1. I just want to test a abstract class's method 'FontData.sGetTextLine()', the code is shown below:**

```cs
namespace Root.Reports {
    internal abstract class FontData {
         internal String sGetTextLine(String sText, Double rWidthMax, ref Int32 iStart, TextSplitMode textSplitMode) {
             if (iStart > sText.Length) {
                 throw new ReportException("start position out of range");
             }
             if (iStart == sText.Length) {
                 iStart++;
                 return "";
             }
             Int32 iStartCopy = iStart;

             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(120);

             // ...
        }
    }
```

}

**2. The calss 'Type1FontData' is a concrete class based on abstract class 'FontData', and the code of Type1FontData is:**

```cs
namespace Root.Reports {
   internal class Type1FontData : FontData {
      internal Type1FontData(FontDef fontDef, String _sFontName, FontStyle fontStyle)
      : base(fontDef, fontStyle, FontData.Encoding.Cp1252)
   {
      // .....
   }
 }
```

}

**3. Then Pex help me to generate a PUT class method 'FontDataTest.sGetTextLine() ':**

```cs
namespace Root.Reports {
  [PexClass(typeof(FontData))]
  [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
  [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(ArgumentException), AcceptExceptionSubtypes = true)]
  [TestClass]
  public partial class FontDataTest
  {
    /// <summary>Test stub for sGetTextLine(String, Double, Int32&amp;, TextSplitMode)</summary>
    [PexMethod(TestEmissionFilter= PexTestEmissionFilter.All)]
    internal string sGetTextLine(
        [PexAssumeNotNull]FontData target,
        string sText,
        double rWidthMax,
        ref int iStart,
        TextSplitMode textSplitMode
    )
    {
        string result = target.sGetTextLine(sText, rWidthMax, ref iStart, textSplitMode);
        return result;
        // TODO: add assertions to method FontDataTest.sGetTextLine(FontData, String, Double, Int32&, TextSplitMode)
    }
   }
 }
```

}

**4. After I run the Pex Exploration, Pex show a message "Guess how to create Root.Reports.Type1FontData". Then I Click the "Edit Factory" and Pex create a class Type1FontDataFactory, the code is**

```cs
namespace Root.Reports
{
public static partial class Type1FontDataFactory
{
    [PexFactoryMethod(typeof(RT), "Root.Reports.Type1FontData")]
    public static Type1FontData Create(
        FontDef fontDef_fontDef,
        string _sFontName_s,
        FontStyle fontStyle_i,
        FontDef fontDef_fontDef1,
        object oFontDataX_o,
        BitArray bitArray_UsedChar_bitArray
    )
    {
        Type1FontData type1FontData
           = new Type1FontData(fontDef_fontDef, _sFontName_s, fontStyle_i);
        type1FontData.fontDef = fontDef_fontDef1;
        type1FontData.oFontDataX = oFontDataX_o;
        type1FontData.bitArray_UsedChar = bitArray_UsedChar_bitArray;
        return type1FontData;

        // TODO: Edit factory method of Type1FontData
        // This method should be able to configure the object in all possible ways.
        // Add as many parameters as needed,
        // and assign their values to each field by using the API.
    }
}
```

}

**5. When I run the Pex Exploration again, then I got the PexAssumeFailedException "could not create an instance of Root.Reports.Type1FontData".**

**6. the dynamic code coverage summay of Type1FontDataFactory.Create() shown the user code or test only covered the following code:**

```cs
Type1FontData type1FontData
           = new Type1FontData(fontDef_fontDef, _sFontName_s, fontStyle_i);
```

**My question is how to hanle this problem, please help me!

Thank you all !**

Answer (score 0):

PexFactory method is use to create instance of complex type.In your case FontData is abstract class.You can nor create instance of abstract class.
Use below attribute before method call.

```
[PexUseType(typeof(Type1FontData ))]
[PexMethod(TestEmissionFilter= PexTestEmissionFilter.All)]
     internal string sGetTextLine(
         [PexAssumeNotNull]FontData target,
         string sText,
         double rWidthMax,
         ref int iStart,
         TextSplitMode textSplitMode 
     )
     {
        string result = target.sGetTextLine(sText, rWidthMax, ref iStart, textSplitMode);
        return result;
        // TODO: add assertions to method 
        FontDataTest.sGetTextLine(FontData, String, Double, Int32&, TextSplitMode)
    }    
    }
}
```